# Force Anaconda to use Python 3.4 on Windows 7

Tags: python, version, pyinstaller

I'm trying to compile a Python script to an .exe using PyInstaller.  I am compiling a 32-bit application which must use Python 3.4.  Python 3.4 is only compatible with PyInstaller 3.4 or older, so I am using PyInstaller v3.3.1. I am using an Anaconda environment.

I would activate my Virtual Environment, which says it is Python version 3.4.5.  Then I would run
`pyinstaller --onefile script.py`.  For some reason, my virtual environment then decides to use Python 3.6.  I am wondering how I can force my script to use Python 3.4.

I have tried `py -3.4 -m pyinstaller ....`, but it says py is not a recognized command.  I then tried to add it to Path, but it still did not work.  Please see below for screen shots.

[image]

and

[image]

Comment: Did you use Python 3.4 to install `pyinstaller` into your virtualenv?

Comment: _I have tried `py -3.4 -m pyinstaller` ...., but it says py is not a recognized command._ Have you tried with `python` instead of `py` ?

Comment: @AMC Yes, the error is: -3 is not a recognized command.

Comment: @MattDMo this might be the issue.  I read the PyInstaller requirements.  version 3.4 or older can be ran on Python 3.4 or older, however, whenever I conda install pyinstaller of any version, it forces me to use Python 3.6.  Is there a way to prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

First, use the `conda` command to uninstall PyInstaller:

```
conda uninstall pyinstaller
```

Next, activate your virtual environment, run

```
python --version
```

to ensure you're using Python 3.4, then run

```
python -m pip install pyinstaller==3.3.1
```

to install that version of PyInstaller to your virtualenv. You should then be able to run

```
pyinstaller --onefile pyopc_da_connector.py
```

or whatever the name of the file is, and you should be all set.

Comment: Hey Matt, I tried to run that on Python 3.4.5.  I got the error saying "No matching distribution found for pyinstaller==3.3.1.

Comment: @RuiNian that's weird, it's working for me. Maybe try `pip list` to make sure `pyinstaller` isn't already installed somewhere else, then run `python -m pip install --force-reinstall pyinstaller<=3.4`

Comment: Hmm no luck unfortunately.  I tried pyinstaller<=3.4, but it says "the system cannot find the file specified".  I then just typed in ==3.3.1, but it says "Could not find a version that satisifies the requirement pyinstaller"

Comment: I downgraded my anaconda to version 2.3.1 where it only has Python 3.4.  Now, I can't even install pyinstaller at all lool.  I'm guessing pyinstaller no longer supports Python older than 3.6?